# Mindbody API integrations blocker

Tags: python, mindbody

I'm planning to develop an app with mindbody integrations api. I heard that we need a site-id (which is the customer id) to be able to develop and test an app. Is that right? This seems like a blocker. Don't they have a sandbox environment with which we can develop and test the apps?

Comment: This is very likely all answered on their site... Look at this [page](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/). It says you need to register to get access to a sandbox...

Answer (score 0):

Mindbody provides a sandbox studio.

Having an account created at https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Home/LogIn gives you access to more API related information, including a link to sandbox account and credentials to login.

Comment: apparently they don't let us publish an app /develop an app into their market place unless we have a site id from an existing customer. Is that right or am I misguided. If I have to publish an app to their market place, do I first need to work with a MindBody customer and . get his site id .Sorry for my long question.